# inject basename of path into find exec command

Tags: php, bash, silverstripe-4

I have a PHP command that works:

```
php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/upgrade-code add-namespace "Vendor\Module\Finaldir" mymodule/finaldir  --write -r -vvv" \;
```

I would like to wrap this into a `find -exec` call (or similar) to do this recursively for folders.

```
find mymodule/src -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c "DIR=$(basename {}); php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/upgrade-code add-namespace "Vendor\\Module\\${DIR}" {}  --write -r -vvv" \;
```

Unfortunately, the code above not work (and also does does not include the capital for the basename (DIR) variable).

What is the best way to achieve this?

I am not married to find at all, I am happy to use anything else, but hopefully I can keep it to one line.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a shell quoting issue and has very little to do with `find` as such.

In a Unix shell (such as bash), variable expansions like `${dir}` are performed by the shell before being passed to the command-line utility, unless they are enclosed in *single quotes*. You can see the result of this by using the `echo` command:

```
$ dir=/home/rici
$ echo $dir     # Unquoted; the expansion is performed
/home/rici
$ echo "$dir"   # Double-quoted; the expansion is performed
/home/rici
$ echo '$dir'   # Single-quoted; the string is passed unmodified
$dir
```

(Note: You shouldn't use all-caps shell variable names. Variable names in all-caps, like `$PATH` and `$USER`, are reserved for use by the system itself. Your own variable names should be in lower-case.)

The difference between the plain version and the double-quoted version is that the double-quoted version preserves whitespace and file-pattern characters, while the unquoted version effectively splits the result of the expansion into separate words and then attempts to expand file patterns in the result:

```
$ ls             # Files in this directory
a  b
$ dir='go   *'   # Note extra spaces
$ echo $dir      # The variable's value is re-split and expanded
go a b
$ echo "$dir"    # Just the value of the variable
go   *
$ echo '$dir'    # Just the characters of the argument
$dir
```

Note that in the unquoted version, the three spaces following `go` have disappeared. The value of `$dir` has been split into two words, and then since the second word is a file pattern, it is expanded into the two filenames. So `echo` is called with three arguments -- `go`, `a` and `b` -- which it prints with a single space separating them.

When the command line utility is a shell interpreter, this affects whether the variable used belongs to the outer shell (and is expanded before the command line is passed to the inner shell), or is passed as a literal string to the inner shell, which then expands it when it is executed:

```
$ dir=outer
$ bash -c "dir=inner; echo $dir"
outer

$ bash -c 'dir=inner; echo $dir'
inner
```

Neither of those formulations are really correct, since the inner shell sees an unquoted parameter expansion, which can lead to unwanted word splitting and filename expansions. Normally, the version we would use would be:

```
bash -c 'dir=inner; echo "$dir"'
```

(In this case, since the double quotes are within single quotes, they are also treated by the outer shell as just ordinary characters, so they are passed through to the inner shell.)

One of the problems with `find -exec bash -c` is that the filename inserted into the command line by `find -exec` is inserted as-is. That allows a carefully-crafted filename to be used as an [injection attack](https://xkcd.com/327/).

To avoid that, we usually take advantage of the fact that `bash -c` also allows us to pass positional arguments to the shell. The arguments to `bash -c` after the command to be interpreted are assigned to `$0`, `$1`, and so on. Since `$0` is not a real positional argument -- it's supposed to be the name of the script -- we usually put a dummy argument (`_` in the example below) after the command argument and before the real positional arguments. So we'll end up with something like this:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Here, I've carefully single-quoted the command-line argument, so that it will be passed as-is; inside the command-line argument I double-quote the parameter expansion so that spaces and stars won't cause any problems, and then I get `find -exec` to pass the filename as the third argument to `bash -c`, where it will become `$1`. I hope that's all clear.

So, to return to the original question, we can apply the above pattern. But I'm going to make one little change; instead of using `basename` to find the last component of the filename, I'm going to use the slightly mysterious shell syntax for deleting the prefix of a variable. `${var##*/}` takes the value of `$var` and then removes the longest prefix matching the pattern `*/`. (A single `#` would have been the shortest match.) The longest prefix matching `*/` is the entire directory path, since it extends to the last `/`; what's left after removing that is precisely the basename.

```
find mymodule/src -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d \
     -exec sh -c 'dir=${1##*/}; php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/upgrade-code add-namespace "Vendor\\Module\\$dir" "$dir" --write -r -vvv' _ {} \;
```

Comment: what an amazing answer... Thank you sooooooooooooo much!